Cucumber HTML Report includes some Features not executed
Running tests using Cucumber.js from CLI always generates HTML Reports with some Features that weren't executed on that run.
Example, executing a single Scenario:
$ ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --name "Invalid user log in - username and password are invalid"
...
Feature: 03. Authentication # features\03_authentication.feature:2
...
  Scenario: Invalid user log in - username and password are invalid # features\03_authentication.feature:10
...
1 scenario (1 passed)
6 steps (6 passed)
0m09.502s (executing steps: 0m09.454s)

Looking into the generated report, the Feature that includes the executed Scenario is listed as executed and some other Features are listed as well, as not executed.

cucumber.js file
const common = [
    'features/**/*.feature',
    '--require-module ts-node/register',
    '--require features/step-definitions/**/*.ts',
    '--format @cucumber/pretty-formatter',
    '--format json:reports/bdd.json',
    '--format html:reports/bdd.html'
    ,"--format-options '{\"colorsEnabled\": true}'"
].join(' ');

module.exports = {
    default: common
}

This always happens and odd thing is that only some extra Features are added, not all, and always the same ones.
I would like to have this sorted, as it isn't direct to navigate to what was indeed executed. Thank you!
